# Excel: A Macro to copy predefined range of cell from one workbook and "Insert" into another at Active Cell location

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to record a Macro and link it to a button to do the following:

1. Copy a predefined range of cells from a Sheet that contains a template for this new section that I wish to add.
2. Insert those cells into another Sheet at the location of the active cell.

When I do this using a Macro, it always inserts the copied cells at the location of the active cell when the Macro was recorded.  Is there a way to have it run based on the location of the current Active Cell?  The other issues is that I have to select a row on the location where I want to insert the cells.

I would appreciate some help with this please?

Comment: Use `ActiveCell` instead of `Range("whatever")` that the recorded code has? It might help if you [edit] your question to create a [reprex] with the current code you have.

Answer (score 0):

## Insert Entire Rows From Another Worksheet

### Active Cell (Any)

**Main**

```
Sub InsertPO()
    InsertRows "4:22"
End Sub
```

**Help**

```
Sub InsertRows(ByVal SourceRows As String)
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Insert Rows (From Template)"
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Templates"
    
    Dim dcell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dcell = ActiveCell
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If dcell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no active cell!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcell.EntireRow
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Rows(SourceRows)
    
    srg.Copy
    drg.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    
End Sub
```

### Active Cell in `ThisWorkbook`

**Main**

```
Sub InsertPO()
    InsertRows "4:22", "OCSC"
End Sub
```

**Help**

```
Sub InsertRows(ByVal SourceRows As String, ByVal DestinationSheetName As String)
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Insert Rows"
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Templates"
    
    Dim dcell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dcell = ActiveCell
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If dcell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no active cell!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DestinationSheetName)
    
    If Not dcell.Worksheet Is dws Then
        MsgBox "This code is only used for worksheet """ _
            & DestinationSheetName & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcell.EntireRow
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Rows(SourceRows)
    
    srg.Copy
    drg.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008. Can you make one alteration? I would like for the cells to be inserted to any sheet that is currently active as opposed to just OCSC. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks VBasic2008.  That works great.  Your help is appreciated.